# Display to multiple monitor at the same time on full screen

Tags: pyqt5

I am working on an art project to display graphic on multiple screen (9+ screens) at the same time. The graphic has very low frequency and low resolution. The graphic is rendered in python, so I thought it would be simple to use pyqt5 to display them. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927021/how-to-display-image-on-secondary-monitor-in-full-screen) is able to display the app to two screen. I wonder if it's possible to extend it to 9+ screens.

Comment: Instead of asking if it's possible, why don't you try it? The linked post only uses one "mirror" screen, just extend it to do the same for as many screens you need.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the comment. I am asking to have a rough idea before I buy all the material. I do want different screen to have different images though. Just to confirm, it seems to me in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927021/how-to-display-image-on-secondary-monitor-in-full-screen) that they are displaying two different things on two different screens, not "mirroring", is that correct?